# Agent Unreachable after restore VMware Horizon Connection Server

Tags: vmware

After a power outage I got both of my View Connection Servers unbootable with BSOD and I could not recovery it and also I don't have backup of it.

After all steps below I could not get things fixed, all VMs are "Agent Unreachable"

Created a new VM for connection server (WITH THE SAME NAME AS THE OLD "VIEWCS01")

> Before doing it correctly I connected the base disk, and not the last
> snapshot, to the new VM and broke up the whole thing with the error
> "file system specific implementation of ioctl [file] failed", I solved
> this correcting the CID - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1007969

- Installed Windows (Same version)
- As in https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76770:

  - Installed Connection Server (Same Version)
  - Restored LDF backup
  - Removed all View Connection Servers and all Security Servers `(vdmadmin -S -s -r viewcs01, viewss01 and viewcs02)`
  - Uninstalled the connection server
  - Reinstalled the connection server reusing the AD LDS

> I did removed the "viewcs01" because with my previous tests I was not removing it, I think because of >this, after the recovery steps done no console was opening, In previous tests I also not using the old >machine name, instead of it I was using "viewcs03".

Ok, Console opened, I changed the vCenter credentials (Just putting password was not working with error - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/60152 - Log below:

```
2020-12-31T18:23:48.108-02:00 ERROR (18F8-0D0C) <MessageFrameWorkDispatch> [ws_java_bridgeDLL] BCryptDecrypt FAILED, status={Data Error}
An error in reading or writing data occurred. (0xC000003E)
2020-12-31T18:23:48.109-02:00 ERROR (18F8-0C54) <VCHealthUpdate> [SecurityManagerUtil] decryptAsText: com.vmware.vdi.crypto.SecurityManagerException: decrypt: Cannot decrypt: Cipher scheme decryption failed.
2020-12-31T18:23:48.109-02:00 DEBUG (18F8-0C54) <VCHealthUpdate> [ServiceConnection25] Connecting instance VCHealth Test instance at URL https://vcenterd.DOMAIN.net:443/sdk
```

Corrected Composer credentials, and added license.

All machines are "Agent Unreachable" - Connection Server Log below:

```
2020-12-31T18:23:49.160-02:00 DEBUG (18F8-1A6C) <DesktopControlJMS> [DesktopTracker] CHANGEKEY message from agent/bda3fbe6-029c-41f8-b9f8-017af574f56b accepted as key and thumbprints match machine record
2020-12-31T18:23:49.162-02:00 DEBUG (18F8-1A6C) <DesktopControlJMS> [DesktopTracker] found broker thumbprints: 0f:9e:80:5d:f6:33:c7:1b:a2:d5:8c:9a:9f:12:45:16:0f:6f:c0:2b:46:8d:d0:33:62:87:53:a9:48:8d:57:8c#SHA_256;51:c5:d0:44:02:7f:ca:6d:5a:ad:5b:f6:8d:f5:11:23:e8:aa:e1:91:d0:5c:ff:71:3b:fb:e2:4b:f4:12:5e:d5#SHA_256
2020-12-31T18:23:49.162-02:00 WARN  (18F8-1A6C) <DesktopControlJMS> [JMSMessageSecurity] Failed to sign message: Cannot sign message
2020-12-31T18:23:49.162-02:00 DEBUG (18F8-1A6C) <DesktopControlJMS> [DesktopTracker] CHANGEKEY message from agent/bda3fbe6-029c-41f8-b9f8-017af574f56b result: true (success)
```

Excerpt from VM agent log:

```
2020-12-31T19:53:44.322-03:00 DEBUG (1EDC-0FA8) <Thread-4> [AgentJmsConfig] Using paired signing key
2020-12-31T19:53:44.322-03:00 DEBUG (1EDC-0FA8) <Thread-4> [AgentMessageSecurityHandler] Configuring message security (ENHANCED).
2020-12-31T19:53:44.369-03:00 DEBUG (1EDC-0FA8) <Thread-4> [BrokerUpdateUtility] Published CHANGEKEY request
2020-12-31T19:53:59.386-03:00 DEBUG (1EDC-0FA8) <Thread-4> [BrokerUpdateUtility] Timeout waiting for success response
2020-12-31T19:59:33.944-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [JmsManager] Using connection broker viewcs01.DOMAIN.net
2020-12-31T19:59:33.944-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2494) <MessageFrameWorkDispatch> [MessageFrameWork] KeyVault service got operation=getEndEntityCertificates, ok=1, msecs=0
2020-12-31T19:59:33.944-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2494) <MessageFrameWorkDispatch> [MessageFrameWork] KeyVault service got operation=getEndEntityCertificates, ok=1, msecs=0
2020-12-31T19:59:33.975-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [JmsManager] username for swiftmq connection is: agent/90916ab8-704c-4fe3-a605-c4a7745b246e
2020-12-31T19:59:33.975-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [AgentJmsConfig] Skipping pair operation: already paired
2020-12-31T19:59:33.975-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [AgentMessageSecurityHandler] Configuring message security (ENHANCED).
2020-12-31T19:59:33.975-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [JmsManager] Re-connecting using secure port 4002
2020-12-31T19:59:34.381-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2780) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-2> [AgentSSLSocketFactory] Received cert with subject cn=router/viewcs01
2020-12-31T19:59:34.381-03:00 WARN  (1430-2780) <SwiftMQ-ConnectorPool-2> [AgentSSLSocketFactory] Certificate thumbprint verification failed, no matching thumbprint. Presented identity: router/viewcs01
2020-12-31T19:59:34.381-03:00 DEBUG (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [JmsManager] Unable to connect to JMS server viewcs01.DOMAIN.net com.vmware.vdi.logger.Logger.debug(Logger.java:44)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unexpected certificate: router/viewcs01
2020-12-31T19:59:34.381-03:00 WARN (1430-2558) <Thread-4> [JmsManager] Unable to connect to any listed host. The agent will continue to retry: [viewcs02.DOMAIN.net, viewcs01.DOMAIN.net]
```

Reinstalled the agent and also tried the command below, as mentioned in https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2038679, nothing has worked at all.

`vdmadmin -A -d desktop-pool-name -m name-of-machine-in-pool -resetkey`

Update to question:
Some piece (That I don't have now) of the log lead me to [This KB](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76302), so I have uninstalled the Connection Server, remove all certificates and reinstalled it again, nothing changed.

After reading the following links [[1]](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon/2006/horizon-security/GUID-4BBC13C6-900A-44B9-B4A3-C90EE3F3BCA9.html), [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/4wp9i6/horizon_7_cant_change_message_security_mode/), [[3]](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2110760):
I've changed the security mode to Mixed, nothing changed.

But after change it to mixed and after reinstalling the Agent (I've reinstalled it before change to mixed and it didn't worked) from the VM have turned it to Available, I still not able to access machine with tunnel errors (Changed tunnel configurations also).

Updated the Connection Server to 7.13, stopped to open console.

Started the whole process from zero, now machine name is viewcs04, not worked also.

For any who encounter the same problem, I decided to create a new Connection Server and I will create manual pools, so people can work and I will migrate everyone to new linked-clone pools.

Just to mention, I cannot just create new pools, all pools are dedicated and have manually installed applications, printers etc.